# "Cannot Load platform/lib/nbexec.dll. Module cannot be found" in Netbeans 7.1

Tags: netbeans, module

I recently installed a Nokia SDK 2.0 and a JDK 7.
But after the Netbeans Update, this error is coming.
Please Help.

Answer (score 4):

Check the task manager and remove netbean instance if it still there and than restart neatbean

if its not working than change path in the start in by right clicking on netbean icon on desktop

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.2.1
```

to

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.2.1\bin
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case it happened when i updated Netbeans. During restart it showed me the error message. Although there was the nbexec.dll file it showed the error. So i thought of replacing that file.To replace it follow steps below.

1.open this link http://originaldll.com/download/31707.dll

2.enter the numbers click on download

3.download this file and replace it from the installation folder...done!!

Comment: Can you please elaborate why this solves the issue and not just how to solve it.